# How do merge rows based on IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I've got two tables, one with this type of structure:

```
id | user_id | field_type_id | value
-------------------------------------
1  | 1       | 1             | John Doe
2  | 1       | 2             | 0800 111 222
3  | 1       | 3             | johndoe@aol.comm
4  | 2       | 1             | Alice Cooper
5  | 2       | 2             | 0800 222 333
6  | 3       | 1             | Ben Sparks
7  | 3       | 3             | ben@gmail.com
```

And i've got another table with the field type IDs:

```
field_type_id | name
-----------------------------
1             | Name
2             | Phone Number
3             | Email Address
```

What kind of query can I run to get the following output:

```
user_id | name         | phone        | email
--------------------------------------------------
1       | John Doe     | 0800 111 222 | Johndoe@aol.com
2       | Alice Cooper | 0800 222 333 | NULL
3       | Ben Sparks   | NULL         | ben@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming user_id is unique (otherwise throw in a DISTINCT) you could do a group by on user id on the first table and then join on that with itself for each type. It would look like this

```
WITH UniqueUsers AS (SELECT user_id FROM table1 GROUP BY user_id)
 
SELECT UniqueUsers.user_id,
  names.value AS name,
  phone.value AS phone,
  email.value AS email
FROM UniqueUsers
LEFT JOIN table1 AS names ON UniqueUsers.user_id = names.user_id AND names.field_type_id = 1
LEFT JOIN table1 AS phone ON UniqueUsers.user_id = phone.user_id AND phone.field_type_id = 2
LEFT JOIN table1 AS email ON UniqueUsers.user_id = email.user_id AND email.field_type_id = 3
```

Comment: Did you forget a `DISTINCT` in the CTE?

Comment: I assumed uniqueness of the user id, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can `join`, and pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select a.user_id
    max(a.value) filter(where f.name = 'name')  as name,
    max(a.value) filter(where f.name = 'phone') as phone,
    max(a.value) filter(where f.name = 'email') as email
from attributes a
inner join fieldtypes f on f.field_type_id = a.field_type_id
group by userid
```